# work item migration, but custom fields where not available on the target environment

Tags: custom-fields, scrum, azure-devops-migration-tools

we started the worktime migration from DEVOP to other DEVOPS
but we forget to create the board columns and a custom field Stakeholder (identity)
So, we created and did run the migration tool again, but it did not set that stakeholder field.
how can this be corrected?
[image]
also the assignment to the board column did not get corrected

we rerun it again, but it did not update those fields

Answer (score 0):

By default, any fields that exist with the same name on the Source will be automatically mapped to the Target. If there is a difference you will need to map the fields.

https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/Reference/